# UICollectionViewCell Size equal to UICollectionView size

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to have  UICollectionView Cell Size equal to width and height of the UICollectionView.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGSize size=collectionView.bounds.size;
    return CGSizeMake(414.0, 586.0);
}
```

If I use `size` then it throws Autolayout error `the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.`  as the height is 
650.0; It works fine if I set the height to 586.0f

```
UICollectionView frame = (0 0; 414 650); 
contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 514}
```

So, how can i fix this height issue?

Answer (score 2):

for iOS 9/10 try next UIController method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGSize scrollSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    UIEdgeInsets inset =  layout.sectionInset;
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(scrollSize.width - inset.left - inset.right, scrollSize.height - inset.top - inset.bottom)];

    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```